# Visualization of Distribution of Angles using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, angle

I have a csv file having two columns as shown:

[image]

The Track_Angle_Ctrl is a column having angles in degrees. The number of rows here is 371.
What is the best way to visualize the distribution of these 371 angles. Is it by using rose diagrams? If so, how to proceed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Python has many options of visualizing a distribution.

- You may start with Pandas `df["Track_Angle_Ctrl"].describe()` to see the general distribution
- For graphical presentation, Seaborn provides displot for plotting histogram, which automatically seperate your data into groups and plot the count: `sns.displot(df, x="Track_Angle_Ctrl")`

You may check here for documentation: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html